# Quicktype option parameter handling

Tags: ios, json, swift, quicktype

I have an optional parameter in my web-service response which can or can not return null. What will be the best what to manage those?

As if I pass null in creator lets say for this structure:

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "profilePicture": null,
    "firstTime": true,
    "preference1": {
        "$id": "26",
        "$values": []
    },
    "Preference2": {
        "$id": "27",
        "$values": []
    }
}
```

Now *profilePicture* is set to **JSONNull** and next time when I actually get profile URL it will not parse that and my response data to ***LNUser*** is nil. If I set this variable to String and *null* received response get set to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
let profilePicture:URL?
```

Answer (score 0):

quicktype needs an exhaustive set of examples, so make sure one of your samples includes a non-null value. Like this: https://app.quicktype.io?share=ldXiDP9cIKB1Q7CPJ7Id